# obtain a working Apache Karaf instance into JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: jboss7.x, apache-karaf

I want to have an Apache Karaf runtime working inside JBoss Application Server 7.1. Theoretically it works, but following [these steps](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-5544), it fails finding some dependencies and the console is not full operative.

Basically, the steps previously mentioned modify the `standalone.xml` configuration file adding an OSGi subsystem:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="eager">
            <properties>
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">
                    1
                </property>
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra">
                    org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot;version=2.2.9
                </property>
            </properties>
            <capabilities>
                <capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>
                <capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.asm:3.3.1_1" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.aries:org.apache.aries.util:0.3.1" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.aries.proxy:org.apache.aries.proxy:0.3.1" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.karaf.jaas:org.apache.karaf.jaas.config:2.2.9" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.karaf.jaas:org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules:2.2.9" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.karaf.shell:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.2.9" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.karaf.shell:org.apache.karaf.shell.commands:2.2.9" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.karaf.shell:org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.2.9" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.1" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:0.7.0" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.karaf.shell:org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh:2.2.9" startlevel="1"/>
            </capabilities>
        </subsystem>
```

But JBoss log show these exceptions:

```
14:30:29,220 ERROR [org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl] (Blueprint Extender: 3) Unable to start blueprint container for bundle org.apache.karaf.jaas.config: org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to intialize bean proxyLoginModuleInitializer
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:640)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:726)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:64)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:219)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:147)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:631)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:337)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/karaf/jaas/boot/ProxyLoginModule
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.config.impl.ProxyLoginModuleInitializer.init(ProxyLoginModuleInitializer.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:225)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:838)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:638)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.ProxyLoginModule from [Module "deployment.org.apache.karaf.jaas.config:2.2.9" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 23 more

14:30:29,455 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (Blueprint Extender: 1) Failed to define class org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.SpringStateListenerFactory$SpringApplicationListener in Module "deployment.org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.2.9" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/karaf/shell/osgi/SpringStateListenerFactory$SpringApplicationListener (Module "deployment.org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.2.9" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.FilteredLocalLoader.loadClassLocal(FilteredLocalLoader.java:46)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.SpringStateListenerFactory.createListener(SpringStateListenerFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.SpringStateListenerFactory.getListener(SpringStateListenerFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.SpringStateListenerFactory.init(SpringStateListenerFactory.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:225)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:838)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:638)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:726)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:64)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:219)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:147)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:631)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:337)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/osgi/context/event/OsgiBundleApplicationContextListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [rt.jar:1.6.0_39]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.osgi.context.event.OsgiBundleApplicationContextListener from [Module "deployment.org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.2.9" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 40 more

14:30:29,518 INFO  [org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils] (Blueprint Extender: 3) BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
```

Then connecting to Karaf console, a bad configuration is obtained. Obtaining an OSGi bundle list:

```
START LEVEL 1 , List Threshold: -1
   ID   State         Blueprint      Level  Name
[   0] [Active     ] [            ] [    0] system.bundle (0.0.0)
[   2] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] JBossOSGi Http API (1.0.5)
[   4] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] Apache Felix Log Service (1.0.0)
[   8] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: asm (3.3.1.1)
[  10] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] Apache Aries Proxy Bundle (0.3.1)
[  14] [Active     ] [Created     ] [    1] Apache Karaf :: Shell :: Console (2.2.9)
[   6] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.2.8)
[  16] [Active     ] [Created     ] [    1] Apache Karaf :: Shell :: OSGi Commands (2.2.9)
[  12] [Active     ] [Failure     ] [    1] Apache Karaf :: JAAS :: Config (2.2.9)
[  18] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] Apache Mina SSHD :: Core (0.7.0)
[   1] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] osgi.enterprise (4.2.0.201003190513)
[   3] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] javax.transaction.api
[   5] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] JBossOSGi Logging (1.0.0)
[   7] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] JBoss Application Server: OSGi ConfigurationAdmin (7.1.1.Final)
[  19] [Active     ] [Created     ] [    1] Apache Karaf :: Shell :: SSH (2.2.9)
[  17] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] Apache MINA Core (2.0.1)
[   9] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] Apache Aries Util (0.3.1)
[  11] [Active     ] [Created     ] [    1] Apache Aries Blueprint Bundle (0.3.2)
[  15] [Active     ] [Created     ] [    1] Apache Karaf :: Shell :: Various Commands (2.2.9)
[  13] [Active     ] [GracePeriod ] [    1] Apache Karaf :: JAAS :: Modules (2.2.9)
```

How can I obtain a well-configured Karaf console? I tried adding all the dependencies into the subsytem, but it was a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss has switched to the Fuse product for all OSGI related implementations.
This means that the OSGI technology preview subsystem is even removed in EAP 6.1+. [source1](https://community.jboss.org/thread/229889) [source2](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Release_Notes_6.0.1/ar01s03.html)
Even if you use Karaf in Jboss, it will use the pax web container, and anything from JSF to injects won't be available.
I advise going a different route.

Comment: thank you for your appointment, but it is not an answer to my question. anyway, a year ago the situation was different and I developed alternative ways to achieve my goal.